# Textbooks and/or other resources for maths to be used in physics at university

Tags: homework-and-exercises, resource-recommendations, education

I am to start university soon but can't seem to wait, I looked through some lecture notes for 1st year content and have not been able to find anything that goes through exactly what I need, I am wondering if any of you could direct me to something which goes through all the mathematical concepts like 4x4 matrices etc so that I can get a head a little.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Math-for-physics books recommendation plea - with two twists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348849/)

Comment: The textbooks assigned by your professors would be a good place to start.

Comment: *mathematical concepts like 4x4 matrices* A $4\times 4$ matrix is just like a $3\times 3$ matrix, except it has $4$ rows and columns instead of $3$.